# dead-lock free vs. starvation free

Tags: algorithm, concurrency, synchronization, parallel-processing, deadlock

Can it happen that mutual exclusion  algorithm doesn`t maintain dead-lock free property,but it maintains  starvation freedom ?

Thank you

Comment: What is your definition of starvation?

Answer (score 19):

**Starvation-freedom** can be defined as: Whatever the process *p*, each invocation of `acquire_mutex()` issused by *p* eventually terminates.
OR Any process trying to enter critical section, will eventually enter critical section.

**Deadlock-freedom**: Whatever the time *T* , if before *T* one or several processes
have invoked the operation `acquire_mutex()` and none of them has terminated its
invocation at time *T* , then there is a time *T' > T* at which a process that has invoked `acquire_mutex()` terminates its invocation.[Raynal, Concurrent Programming: Algorithms, Principles, and Foundations]
OR If process is trying to enter critical section, then some process, not necessary same one, eventually will enter critical section. OR At least one, always wins.

Notice, that deadlock-freedom is saying that there are **some** processes will make progresses, but others might be stuck(starving), trying to get into critical section. It sound weird at first, but it is so: not all threads are stuck, so there is no deadlock, i.e. deadlock-freedom.

On other hand, starvation-freedom is saying that **every** process trying to get into critical section, will eventually do so. There will be no processes that will ever starve.

This makes starvation-freedom much stronger property than deadlock-freedom.

Answer to your question is NO.

Comment: Well explained!  Let me try make a TLDR version here: Deadlock-free: at least one thread is not starving at any given time.  Starvation-free: No thread will get starved.

Comment: Example of non-deadlock starving:  LIFO style mutex, newer mutex waiter enters the critial section first and there have always been more than one waiter.  Thus the first waiter never get a chance to enter the critical section and thus starves.

Answer (score 7):

No—every reasonable definition of starvation includes deadlock.